# What's the purpose of the secret key for stripe? Also, is this safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

Right now, stripe is integrated with my rails app but I've never used the secret key given to me, I've only used the publishable key. What does the secret key actually do?

Also, I have this bit of code in my views:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  Stripe.setPublishableKey("my-publishable-key-here");
</script>
```

Is putting the publishable key right there safe? The stripe docs actually do the same thing, but I'm just not sure.

Comment: I don't write an answer because I'm not sure about the publishable key, but the secret key should be defined in `/config/initializers/stripe.rb`, stored in an ENV variable, and used under the hood by `gem 'stripe'` to authenticate you to Stripe. Exactly as showed here https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/rails#configuring-the-application

Comment: Actually the only key that everyone can see is the public one. Here is an article that can explain the purpose of those keys (better than I can): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptography#Public-key_cryptography (giving the public key is safe but don't give the secret one! )

Comment: so publishable key = public key?

Comment: the publishable key can only be used to tokenize card data, the secret key is used in your rails code to actually charge the token you create.

Comment: so this can be saved to client side? i mean no need to secure this?

Answer (score 25):

The publishable key is used in your client-side code to tokenize payment information, using [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) or [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js). It can only be used to create tokens, and tokens by themselves do nothing (they're only a representation of a payment source which hides the sensitive information).

The secret key is used in your backend code to send any other request to [Stripe's API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#intro). You need to be careful never to leak your secret key, as it could be used to access your account and cause all sorts of troubles (refunding past charges, canceling subscriptions, deleting saved customers, etc.).

You can find all your API keys in your Stripe dashboard: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys. If you ever need to, you can replace a key with a new one ("roll out" a key) by clicking the small "recycle" icon next to each key.

Comment: so that means publishable key is public key.. and can be placed on client side?

Comment: This is not true, publishable key is only used to rate limit card validation, tokenization happens on Stripe side, customer credit card details are sent via the payload encrypted with https.

Comment: @Smakosh That is not quite correct. The tokenization process occurs between the customer's browser and Stripe, without hitting the merchant's backend. The payload sent by the customer's browser contains the payment source information (e.g. card number, CVC, etc.) and the merchant's publishable key, so that Stripe knows which merchant account to use when creating the payment source.

Comment: @Ywain Stripe already has the payment intent secret / session id and knows who the merchant is.

Comment: Fair -- my original answer was from 2016, long before Checkout Sessions existed. At the time Checkout was a pre-built form embedded on the merchant's site, there was no session or redirect involved. My answer is still applicable if you tokenize data on your site using e.g. by creating a Payment Method using Stripe.js Elements (or basically any other API requests sent using Stripe.js).